# Use Class Library C# variables in a .cshtml <script type="text/javascript"></script>

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, visual-studio, razor

I'm trying to access some C# variables from my js script.
I have a .NET project in VisualStudio, and another WebApp project (MVC template).

I want to access some of the data from my Class Library, in my `.cshtml`, in the part at the bottom of my script where I've added a `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` block.

Is this possible?

I've added the .NET project as a `Reference` for the WebApp, so I can technically access it somehow, but not sure how to pass it or if to use the `Controller` `View()` to do this or some other way...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your current structure is like, so I will be assuming you have a class in our C# DLL e.g.

```
public class Foo 
{
   public string SomeVariableInOurDll => "Test"; //this can be of whatever type
}
```

Now moving to your MVC project. Let's create a view model:

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    public string VariableToReadInJs { get; set; }
}
```

Inside your controller action you can now do:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var foo = new Foo();

        var model = new SomeViewModel
        {
            VariableToReadInJs = foo.SomeVariableInOurDll
        };

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Finally inside your view your js code will be something like:

```
<script>
     var myVal = '@Model.VariableToReadInJs';
     ...
</script>
```

Finally, at the top of your `.cshtml` ensure you use the view model as:

```
@model SomeViewModel
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this helps a lot. I still need to find a way to run my Class Library first and from that activate the WebApp to run whatever it is running, then i'll know if the solution you suggest works completely... thank you again